# Flash file not playing on browser from server

Tags: html, flash, browser, download

I have a flash file on my server and I am trying to open it on my browser. If I call for it directly, it downloads the file. If I embed it in html file and then call the html file, it does not display the flash file. Is there any other way to access it without converting flash file into any other format?

Following is my code in html:-

```
<html>
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" 
codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab" width="498" height="380" id="test1"> 
<param name="movie" value="game.swf" />
<embed src="game.swf" width="498" 
height="380" name="test1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" />
</object>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me that your web server is not configured to serve SWF's (aka: it doesn't know what it is). This is typical on barebones IIS installations. Therefore, it forces a "download file" header when you request the file.

Check your web server config to ensure it is allowing SWF files to be served.

Comment: I am using weblogic server and I've added <mime-mapping> 
  <extension>swf</extension> 
  <mime-type>application/x-shockwave-flash</mime-type>
 </mime-mapping> in my web.xml which should allow the server to read swf files. If you have any experience with weeblogic server, can you suggest any other configurations that need to be updated to allow server to serve swf files.

Comment: oh ok. Along with the mime mapping, adding the following in my weblogic.xml to allow the encoding of path to resources solved the issue:- <charset-params>
  <input-charset>
   <resource-path>*</resource-path>
   <java-charset-name>UTF-8</java-charset-name>
  </input-charset>
 </charset-params>   Thank you.